# Kate install issue

Tags: c++, linux, qt, kate

I'm trying to install Kate from sources.
When I do this:

```
cmake ../kate -DBUILD_KTEXTEDITOR=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debugfull -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/kde/usr
```

it says

```
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
```

After that when I type make command it says:

```
In member function ‘void KateViewInternal::updateSelection(const KTextEditor::Cursor&, bool)’:
 error: ‘TextSelectionChanged’ is not a member of ‘QAccessible’
In member function ‘void KateViewInternal::cursorMoved()’:
 error: ‘TextCaretMoved’ is not a member of ‘QAccessible’
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you doing it so complicated? Just install it with yum, apt-get or whatever fits you.

Answer (score 1):

The TextSelectionChanged item of the `QAccessible::Event` enum appeared in Qt 4.8. Looks like the Kate source you checked out depends on that version, but you have an older one.

You should either pick up and earlier version of Kate, or install a more recent version of Qt and build against that.

(I think the `Q_WS_*` warnings should be harmless, as long as one of them is found - probably `Q_WS_X11` or something like that for Linux.)